# indexed time different from logged time - kibana

Tags: logstash, kibana, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration, kibana-7

The indexed time of the log is different from the logged time of the log.

Logged time - 2021-01-25 04:19:18,002

Indexed time - Jan 25, 2021 @ 04:19:27.750

There is a 10 seconds delay when comparing both the timestamps. Is there a way to make the indexed timestamp same as the logged time timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `date` filter to set the `@timestamp` to the timestamp field of the log.

So if you've got the time in a field called `log_time`, you'd use a `date` filter like this:

```
            date {
                    match => [ "log_time", "ISO8601" ]
            }
```

See the [logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) documentation for additional details on how the `date` filter works.

Comment: I have already tried this but the field log_time is not getting generated in the document. My datestamp in the log looks like - 2021-01-27 06:02:46.424

Comment: My filter plugin looks like this -  filter {
      date {
        match => ["logtime", "ISO8601"]
     }
      grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601} \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s{0,2}] \[%{GREEDYDATA:thread}\] \(%{DATA:collection}\) %{GREEDYDATA:details}" }
      }

    }

Comment: Edit your question with that information. But order matters, and you aren’t assigning the time to logtime in the grok statement

Comment: assigning the time to logtime and using that in date filter worked . Thanks much .